# Why doesn't the NameObjectCollectionBase class provide a way to insert objects into the collection by index?

Tags: .net-3.5

The `System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase` class is used extensively at my company as the basis of collection classes. (Let's not get into questioning why.) I recently came across a situation where I needed to add an object at a specific index, but the functionality wasn't there. At first I wondered why we had left that functionality out of *our* collection classes, but I soon discovered that the functionality is missing from `NameObjectCollectionBase`!

You can access objects in the collection by index (`BaseGet(int index)`).
You can remove objects from the collection by index (`BaseRemoveAt(int index)`).
But you can't insert an object at a specific index.

I can't think of a good reason why this functionality isn't available. Can you?

[Update]The underlying implementation is not just a `HashTable`. The collection maintains both a `HashTable` and an `ArrayList`. You can verify this using Reflector.

Answer (score 3):

Because the underlying implementation is a `HashTable` and inserting directly into it would break it (index is related to the hash of the key).  Expecting what is a hash, except in name, to be ordered (i.e., a particular element exists between two others) in an a sequence not related to the hash of the key value seems a little odd.  If you need it to be ordered, you're probably better off using an `OrderedDictionary` or `SortedDictionary<T,T>`.

More info on [NameObjectCollectionBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.aspx), [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx), and [SortedDictionary<T,T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).

Comment: `NameObjectCollectionBase` is not an ordered collection - you cannot control the order of items in the collection. It may well have an `ArrayList` internally but that is an implementation detail. If you want that behavior you need `OrderedDictionary`.